# Python: how to feed a user-defined value into the middle of a pipeline?

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, command-line, pipe

In a shell script I perform a task by executing 3 Python programs, connected by pipes:

```
cat input.txt | crawl | assess | format > out.txt
```

The `assess` program has a variable `max_text_length` that is assigned a default value:

```
max_text_length = 20
```

I want users to be able to change that value when they run my shell script.

How do I enable users to feed into `assess` a new value for `max_text_length`?

Note: each of my 3 Python programs (`crawl`, `assess`, `format`) read from `stdin` and write to `stdout`. They do not read from the command line.

Comment: [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Comment: argparse, or sys.argv, or set an environment variable.